# Independent events satisfying $P(A_n)<1$

Tags: probability-theory

So I'm working on my mathematical probability class, and I have the following question:  Suppose $\{A_n\}$ are independent events satisfying $P(A_n)<1$ for all $n$.  Show

$P(\bigcup _{n=1}^\infty A_n)$=1  iff $P(A_n i.o.) =1$.
So, the backwards direction was trivial.  For the forward direction,  what I have so far is

$P\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_{n}\right)^{C}=0=P\left(\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}A_{n}^{C}\right)=\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}(1-P\left(A_{n}\right))$ 
Since the $A_n$'s are independent.  Now, since $P(A_n)<1$,  we have  $1-P\left(A_{n}\right)>0$.

Hence, for the infinite product to be $0$,
  we must have an infinite number of $1-P\left(A_{n}\right)<1$,
  hence for an infinite number of $n$'s,
  $P\left(A_{n}\right)>0$.

Now, I'm not sure if that's sufficient. Does that imply the desired conclusion that $P(A_n i.o.)=1$  I feel like it should....(Or did I make another mistake!)

Comment: Actually, "for the infinite product to be $0$" the condition is that the series $\sum\limits_nP(A_n)$ diverges.

Comment: @did It does?  I'm not following....

Comment: @did never mind, found your other answer on this one.  Deleting as a duplicate